# Devise destroy_user_session not working

Tags: html, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have 2 different calls to the same Devise method: destroy_user_session.

The working one is done with a very basic approach and lead to the following HTML code:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a>
```

Them I made a more fancy one, with better UI, but still the same Rails App (so no change, only the resulting HTML is different):

```
<a class="tip" data-confirm="You are going to be disconnected" data-title="Logoff" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" data-original-title="" title=""><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></a>
```

While both are using the same method: delete to destroy current user session the second one returns ***No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"***.

Adding a GET route for /users/sing_out can be an option but not clean as it has to be a DELETE call.

Comment: add to your routes `get "/users/sign_out", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"`

Comment: That's not explaining why one is working and why the other one is not.

Comment: Maybe is the order you put them. Why you don't use `<% link_to %>

Comment: I'm using <% link_to %> to generate both of them.

Comment: I agree the order seems to be the issue for this, but should not.
The order should not override the method that is clearly declared as "DELETE" for both. I still do not understand why the second one is returning a GET instead of requested DELETE.

Comment: Seems to be a JS issue.  The data-method attribute by itself does nothing without Rails' unobtrusive javascript or jquery_ujs.  So the question is how is this link getting into the DOM?  Is it being dynamically inserted into place?  If you(or a script you are relying on) are using something like a jQuery .clone(), .html(), etc. to create that link in it's place it would revert to default link behavior ie. a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was created by "rails ujs javascript" not loading properly on the faulty page.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 7, you will need to use the following instead of just `method: :delete`:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { "turbo-method": :delete } %>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482989/25192