# Rails 7 - link_to with method :delete still performs GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to get this link to work, performing a `DELETE` request:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

However when I click on it, my browser still performs a `GET` request (which fails for obvious reasons):

[image: screenshot of browser network console]

I have read on multiple other forum posts, that this might have something to do with jquery not being included. They mentioned you would need to un-comment a line in `app/javascript/application.js`, however mine is pretty empty:

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
```

These forum posts were also quite old, so I suspect something has changed in the meantime.

Comment: I have not used hotwired, but does changing `method: :delete` to `data: { turbo_method: :delete }` work?

Comment: Yes, this works for me, thanks :) there is only one weird thing: once the DELETE request was performed, my browser is redirected (as desired) but instead of doing a normal GET, it does another DELETE (in my case at "/"). The user doesn't notice it, it just shows up in the network console.

Comment: Check this github issue and specifically this [comment](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/288)
Maybe the destroy_user_session_path and not specifying delete method fires a request twice...

Comment: @Nils - Try adding this `status` in your redirect: `redirect_to action: 'some_action', status: 303`. Because: If you are using XHR requests other than `GET` or `POST` and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double `DELETE`. To work around this you can return a `303 See Other` status code which will be followed using a `GET` request. Also see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Comment: For some general clarification, see: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#disabling-turbo-drive-on-specific-links-or-forms

Comment: What @TomDogg said. I spent over an hour trying to understand why I was getting two redirects. Adding the status: 303 solved it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5439#issuecomment-997927041), the following will suffice:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { "turbo-method": :delete } %>
```

I have tested this in my project and it seems to work fine. Thanks also to [@alexts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612135/alexts), you basically figured this out too, however the comment on GitHub even eliminated the double-request.

Comment: I tried this a few days ago in my project and I could swear it was working. But now when I try this it does not work.

Comment: Could you post what versions of rails and devise you’re using?

Comment: This will not work if you place it in the form because it creates another hidden form. The better way of doing it is using `button_to` as stated in the documentation.
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#performing-visits-with-a-different-method

Comment: `button_to` also creates a form.

Comment: Hey @Nils, just saw your comment. As I said, I tried this and it did work. Then for some reason it did not and frustrated I searched around and left my comment here. And then, a while later, it worked again. I do not know what I did wrong, what changed, but I was happy it did work and totally forgot about the comment I left.

Comment: @imarg : If your `<form>` (or another parent element such as a `<div>`) has `data: { turbo: false }` then you will also need to add `turbo: true` to your `link_to`, resulting in: `<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo: true, turbo_method: :delete } %>`

Comment: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015122/15915143

Comment: The problem in using turbo is , it does not reload static js files.

Answer (score 56):

There are (at least) two ways to delete something in rails 7:

#### Using `button_to` (preferred IMHO):

```
<%= button_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Renders an HTML form which sends a `POST` request with a hidden `_method` attribute with 'delete' value. Rails will treat this as if it has a `DELETE` method (and route it to `products#destroy` or whatever your routes are saying). Do not use this one within another form (HTML [forbids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) one form inside another).

#### Using `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, data: {turbo_method: :delete} %>
```

Renders a simple `a` tag with `data-turbo-method` attribute. This link sends a **real** `DELETE` request.

If your `destroy` action ends with a `redirect_to`, some browsers will redirect to a new location with `DELETE` method (causing errors), so make sure to add `status: :see_other` parameter to `redirect_to`, like the guides [suggest](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article).

#### Confirmation

If you want to add confirmation prompt to a button above:

```
<%= button_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete,
  form: {data: {turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'}} %>
```

If you want to add confirmation to a link above:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path,
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Comment: so if we use it inside form, should we use link_to instead button_to or is there any alternatives?

ref: https://dev.to/paramagicdev/escaping-the-traditional-rails-form-4c4o

Comment: Note that `button_to "text", [url], method: :delete` uses DELETE, whereas `button_to "text", [url], "data-turbo-method": :delete` doesn't (no hidden `_method` input is added to the form). Found that out after replacing hundreds of `link_to` and `button_to`.

Answer (score 12):

**Found it on git**

Run these commands

It worked for me.

```
$ rails importmap:install
$ rails turbo:install stimulus:install
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the missing lines for the rails tutorial to works. I've submitted a PR to improve the documentation with these lines !

Comment: This command will be reset import map with linked all javascript link. it's not working on rails 7.0.8

Comment: Also ran into issues with the Rails tutorial. These two commands solved it. <v7.1.3.2>

Answer (score 3):

I had a more niche case where I'd turned off turbo globally in the rails 7 app [like so](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails#navigate-with-turbo-drive):

```
// app/javascript/application.js
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = false
```

If you did that too, you might need to set `turbo: true` for the button_to approach to work.

Here's what worked for me:

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', @page, method: :delete, form: 
  { data: { turbo: true, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } } %>
```

It's the same as other answers but it ensures turbo is indeed on for that element.

#### Notes

- I didn't need ujs
- I didn't need jquery or `//= require jquery` or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

method: :delete just add a attribute

in order to make it useful, `rails_ujs` library is responsible
try to include it
that can be useful