# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/products/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm practicing with RoR with a CRUD, but when I want delete some product, I got this error (like in the image), I don't know why got this error, someone can help me pleas?

This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  get '/products', to: 'products#index'
  get '/products/new', to: 'products#new'
  post '/products', to: 'products#create'
  post '/products/:id', to: 'products#shows', as: 'product'
  get '/products/:id/edit', to: 'products#edit', as: 'edit_product'
  patch '/products/:id', to: 'products#update'
  delete '/products/:id', to: 'products#delete'
  # resources :products    
end
```

This is my products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  
  def delete
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price)
    end
  
end
```

And this is my index.html.rb, where I'm listing the products.

```
<h1>Products list</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>price %></th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.name %></td>
      <td><%= product.description %></td>
      <td><%= product.price %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to "Update", edit_product_path(product) %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post the error, copy and paste the console output that shows the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using Rails 7 since `method: :delete` is no longer working without `ujs`.

So, it leads to GET request and there is really no such route in your config.
This issue was discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474422/rails-7-link-to-with-method-delete-still-performs-get-request) and the solution is:

```
  <%= link_to "Delete", product, data: {  turbo-method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

But there is a catch: looks like not all versions of Rails 7 support this behavior. And this will not work inside the form because actual mechanics of changing the method is based on creating a hidden form. There is a discussion in the [issue](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/288) and a hint in the [docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#performing-visits-with-a-different-method): you should use links only for `GET` requests. For other requests use actual forms or buttons, so [button_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) will do the job better since it can change method and use confirmation prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I infer that you try to do the `show` action. If it is the case, the HTML verb is wrong. You are using `post` instead of `get`.

The **POST** verb is most often utilized to **create** new resources.

The HTTP **GET** method is used to **read** (or retrieve) a representation of a resource