# Redirect to show action instead of destroy in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Ruby version is 3.1.2 and the rails version is 7.0.3.1

when deleting a user, it's redirecting to show action instead of destroy action in user's controller.
Routes for users

```
resources :users
```

app/controller/users_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_user, only: %i[ destroy ]
def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end

private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
```

app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div id="users">
        <%= render user %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

app/views/users/_user.html.erb

```
<p>
  <%= link_to "Destroy this user", user, method: :delete %>
</p>
```

we are not able to delete user.

i have followed below link but that's also not working in my project
[link_to helper still perfomring get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474422/rails-7-link-to-with-method-delete-still-performs-get-request)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less magic with form

```
<%= button_to "Destroy this user", user, method: :delete %>
```

or more magic with link

```
<%= link_to "Destroy this user", user, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>
```

And don't forget to add `status: :see_other` to `redirect_to users_url`

Rails 7 work such way