# turbo_method: :delete not working for destroying users in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

Can anyone tell me why the following is not working in Rails 7?

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, data: {  turbo_method: :delete } %>
```

The expected action was a DELETE request routed to the `destroy` action from the `UsersController`. The result was a GET request (`GET /users/1`) routed to the `show` action.

I have also tried:

```
data: { turbo: true, turbo_method: :delete }
data: { "turbo-method": :delete }
data: { "turbo_method": :delete }
```

I have `resources :users` in  `routes.rb` with rails routes indicating:

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)     users#show                                                                    
     PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)     users#update                                                                      
     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)     users#update                                                                         
     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)     users#destroy
```

Running:

```
ruby 3.2.2 
rails 7.1.1
turbolinks 5.2.1
```

In previous version of rails this was simply `method: :delete`, but apparently in Rails 7 the more complicated the better.

Comment: have you installed turbo/stimulus? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015122/1081668

Comment: Do I need to install gems for basic REST actions to work??

Comment: yes, because Rails 7 uses Turbo :) Or you may need to remove Turbo and use the old way.

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning is that I have turbolinks installed. Is this deprecated in rails 7? Or can I install the turbo gem next to it?

Comment: it's default when you create new Rails app. Check your Gemfile to see if it has `turbo-rails` gem